# Perl go up a character?

Tags: perl

In Perl, lets say I have the letter A in variable called `$character`, and I want it to go up to B, how would I do this? The `$character` can also be numbers (0-8) and I want the method work on both of them? (Something like binary shift, but not exactly sure if it is something like that). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The increment operator may be what you want. However, do make sure that you want the boundary behavior. For instance:

```
my $character = 'Z';
print ++$character;
```

Produces:

```
AA
```

This is the "with carry" from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement.

Comment: This is the same answer as @perreal's, other than the warning about the carry.   So I'm confused that this one worked and the other didn't?

Comment: @Mark Reed, Probably because he printed the result of `$character++` instead of `$character` when he used perreal's code. It's hard to tell for sure, since he didn't provide the message he actually got or the code he actually used.

Answer (score 8):

Simple increment should do what you want:

```
my $character = "A";
$character++;
```

from [perl-doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement):

> The auto-increment operator has a little extra builtin magic to it. If
>   you increment a variable that is numeric, or that has ever been used
>   in a numeric context, you get a normal increment. If, however, the
>   variable has been used in only string contexts since it was set, and
>   has a value that is not the empty string and matches the pattern
>   /^a-zA-Z*0-9*\z/ , the increment is done as a string, preserving each
>   character within its range, with carry

Comment: it said could not increment because it is not numeric

Comment: I've never seen Perl issue that message.  What version?  This works fine here: `perl -le 'my $character="A"; $character++; print $character;'` => `B`.

Comment: That is not a message Perl [issues](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html). The closest is "Argument ... isn't numeric", but I don't see how you could have gotten that from `++`. Please use the code and the input you actually used.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other responses:

Note that the magical autoincrement only works if the variable in question has never been used in a numeric context.  Thus:

```
perl -e '$x = "A"; ++$x; print $x'  # prints "B"
```

But:

```
perl -e '$x = "A"; $x + 0; ++$x; print $x'  # prints "1"
```

To be guaranteed of always getting the magical autoincrement, you should stringify the variable explicitly beforehand:

```
perl -e '$x = "A"; $x + 0; $x = "$x"; ++$x; print $x'  # prints "B"
```

It may be possible to skip this step if you know the history of the variable you're incrementing and can verify that it has never been used in a numeric context.

Playing with magic can be tricky!